# Make Project Directory in Java

Tags: java

How I make this directory in Netbeans using java code?

ProjectName - PackageName - FileName.java

I tried using File class, but isn't successfully.

Please Help Me !!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking a question, please be sure to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you are using. If you have not written any code yet, chances are good that the question is off-topic for this site. Make sure to do some research and try to solve the problem yourself first. Then, if you still have any specific (non-"give me the code") questions, post a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and we will be happy to help you.

Comment: @MageXy I think he was asking how to use netbeans to create a directory

Comment: @JasonZ I don't think so, he's asking for Java code. As far as Java is concerned, creating a file in a Netbeans directory is the same as creating a directory anywhere else. Of course, perhaps if the question put some effort into explaining what exactly it is they want, we wouldn't have to speculate.

Comment: Please, specify more details about your problem. It's impossible to understand what you need. Please let us know it for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be asking how to create a new project with the ProjectName - PackageName - FileName.java name structure.

1. Start Netbeans IDE
2. Choose File > New Project
3. In the New Project wizard, expand the Java category and select Java Application
4. Add in the project details using the New Project Wizard
5. Click Finish

Take a look at [Netbeans Quick Start Guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html) for more information

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon on SO due to possible link rot (links becoming outdated/invalid/updated to be different/etc). Please include at least a summary of the relevant parts of the link in your answer.

Comment: Updated answer to include information from the link